# json results only showing one thing in table

Tags: html, json

I am havign an issue where there is only one item being shown in my table (usually the most recent bug entered)

could you let me know if there is an error with my code?

Here is it

```
//Web service call to get the data
var getAllBugsData = $.get("https://m2052626.scm.tees.ac.uk/AST_14/Bugg.ly2/index.php/bug/GetAllBugs",



function(data) 
{

var j = 0;
var myTotal = data.length ;



    for(var i =0; i < data.length;i++)
    {

    var item = data[i];


    bug_id = item.bug_id;

    BugType = item.BugType;


    Bugaddress = item.Bugaddress;
    admin_id = item.admin_id;
    status = item.status;

    Description = item.description;
    type = item.type;


    var bugDetails = '<div class="PropDetails">Bug Id: '+bug_id+'</div><div class="PropDetails">Type of Bug: '+BugType+'</div><div class="PropDetails">Admin Number :'+admin_id+'</div><div class="PropDetails">Type Of Bug: '+type+'</div>';



    $('.listAllBugs').append('<tr class="table-stroke"><td>'+bugDetails+'</td><td><a href="#">Edit</a></tr>');
```

And the table code is this

```
<!--Data Table Goes HERE-->
<table data-role="table" data-mode="reflow" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="100%">Bug Details</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="listAllBugs">

            </tbody>
          </table>
```